# Using generic-based role pattern with EntityFramework 4

Tags: entity-framework, generics, role

Maybe I haven't quite get the whole thing about models. I tought that, it was probably wrong, EF framework could map any kind of class. So I did provide classes with different interfaces, with `ToString()` methods and so on.

I was thinking of reusable/flexible structure of classes for some kind of public organization.

For example, there are next classes

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class AbstractRole
{
    public String Title { get; set; }

    public abstract void ExecuteRole();
    public abstract Decimal GetSalary();

    // ToString(...) implementations and so on
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee<T> : IComparable<Employee<T>>, IFormattable where T : AbstractRole
{
    private Person person;        
    public T Role { get; set; }

    // interfaces implementations...       
}
```

So all I wanted is to get flexibility to change employee's role in time and not to bind to its instance (avoid inheritance).

But later I read that generics are not supported by EF.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of entity framework you must provide exact type. Base classes are supported only if whole inheritance tree is mapped as well. Interfaces and generic types are not supported at all.

That means that reusable and flexible architecture is not something which can use EF.

Comment: OK. Is there any alternative way? Let's imagine I'm developing ASP.NET MVC site.

Comment: That is hard to say because I don't know your application. Simply follow basic rule - entity must be persisted by EF = no not mapped abstraction and no generics because EF is not able to use it. If you want such abstraction you will most probably have to use some conversion layer between your domain object and between persisted objects. That will make your architecture very complicated.